# Memory Leak In Javascript from shared closures

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Iam new to javascript and i found an article about memory and a specific example .[article](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/#Leaks-in-JavaScript)

In the example says that :

> The important thing is that once a scope is created for closures that
>   are in the same parent scope, that scope is shared. In this case, the
>   scope created for the closure someMethod is shared by unused

I changed it to the fixed version but the same happens. The someMethod is not in the same parent scope, but the memory leak remains. What am i missing?

```
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
  var originalThing = theThing;
  var unused = function () {
    if (originalThing)
      console.log("hi");
  };
  theThing = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
    someMethod: function () {
      console.log(someMessage);
    }
  };
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

Fixed Version:

```
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
  var originalThing = theThing;
  var unused = function () {
    if (originalThing)
      console.log("hi");
  };
  (function(){
  theThing = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
    someMethod: function () {
      console.log(someMessage);
    }
  };
})()
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

Comment: "*The someMethod is not in the same parent scope*" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Bergi Unsed method has the replaceThing as a parent scope whereas the someMethod  has the anonymous function as a parent scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the two closures are in the exact same scope or not. Introducing an intermediate scope through that IIFE (which, btw, should be optimised away since it contains no variables), doesn't change the fact that `theThing.someMethod` still closes over the `originalThing` variable.

Fixing this particular issue requires manually clearing `originalThing` when it is no longer needed, or declaring it in a scope that the preserved function doesn't have access to:

```
var theThing = null;
function replaceThing() {
  {
    const originalThing = theThing;
    function unused() {
      if (originalThing)
        console.log("hi");
    }
  }
  theThing = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
    someMethod() {
      console.log(someMessage);
    }
  };
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

```
// or, ES5 style:
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
  (function(){
    var originalThing = theThing;
    var unused = function () {
      if (originalThing)
        console.log("hi");
    };
  })();
  theThing = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
    someMethod: function () {
      console.log(someMessage);
    }
  };
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
```

While the particular example could be optimised by a clever compiler, you need to understand the reason why the lexical environment needs to be shared. Consider the code

```
 var log, increment, decrement;
 {
   let heavy = [];
   let count = 0;
   log => {
     console.log(heavy, count);
   };
   increment = () => {
     heavy.push("long string");
     count++;
   };
   decrement = () => {
     count--;
   };
 }
 increment();
 log();
 increment = log = null; // release memory, `heavy` is no more used anywhere?
 decrement();
```

Because `log` and `increment` both refer to `count` and `heavy`, those two variables are placed in the same lexical environment. (Making separate environments for separate variables that could be garbage-collected independently would require switching from a scope chain (simple linked list) to something much more complicated (directed acyclic graph).

But also `decrement` refers to the `count` variable, so it closes over the same environment object. It doesn't matter that `decrement` doesn't use `heavy`. Now when all the functions that did refer to the `heavy` variables got garbage-collected, `decrement` still has a reference to the `heavy` value.

Comment: In the article clearly states that "that once a scope is created for closures that are in the same parent scope, that scope is shared". They arent in the same parent scope but still there is a leak

Comment: @TORO Well, to be precise it should have been "*once a scope is created because of a closure, all functions in that scope share it*". The [original article](https://blog.meteor.com/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak-8b47d2e7f156?gi=856e7bc58c04) on the Meteor blog explains it much better, including the linked chain of lexical environments.

Comment: Thank you very much